# Delayed redirected POST request to another page

Tags: php

i found a error when redirect to other page. here is my code:

payment.php:

```
<form action="payment2.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $payable; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="confirm" value="<?php echo $confirmation; ?>" />
```

payment2.php:

```
header("Refresh: 2;url=paymentGate.php"); 
$pay=$_POST['amount1'];
$confirmation=$_POST['confirm1'];

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Redirects</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=paymentGate.php" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        location.href = 'paymentGate.php';
                    }, 2000);
        </script>

          <input  type="hidden" name="amount1" value="<?php echo $pay; ?>" />
        <input   type="hidden" name="confirm1" value="<?php echo $confirmation; ?>" />
    </head>
    <body>
```

paymentGate.php:

```
$pay=$_POST['amount1'];
$confirmation=$_POST['confirm1'];

echo <?php $pay ?>
echo <?php $confirmation ?>
```

the amount1 and confirm1 are Undefined index in paymentGate.PHP.How to solve this problem?

Comment: use javascript and settimeoutfuntion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make form post after 2 seconds. This would do it.

```
$pay=$_POST['amount1'];
$confirmation=$_POST['confirm1'];

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Redirects</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        document.form1.submit();
                    }, 2000);
        </script>

</head>
    <body>
<form method="post" action="paymentGate.php" name="form1" id="form1">
          <input  type="hidden" name="amount1" value="<?php echo $pay; ?>" />
        <input   type="hidden" name="confirm1" value="<?php echo $confirmation; ?>" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting does not magically resubmit a form. Try something like this instead:

```
<form action="paymentGate.php" method="post" id="myForm">
     <input type="hidden" name="amount1" value="<?php echo $pay; ?>" />
     <input type="hidden" name="confirm1" value="<?php echo $confirmation; ?>" />
</form>
<script>
   setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('myForm').submit() }, 2000);
</script>
```

This will automatically submit the 'faked' form in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect with post data maby be you shold try get menthod

```
 window.location = '/paymentGate.php?amount1='+amount1&confirm1='+confirm1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$pay=$_POST['amount1'];
$confirmation=$_POST['confirm1'];

sleep(5) //5 seconds

echo <?php $pay ?>
echo <?php $confirmation ?>
```

Comment: I have no clue what this is supposed to do.

Comment: This will halt the code from execution for 5 seconds then continue processing